# Biber not recognized on Windows 7 64-bit after installing it into the localtexmf tree

Tags: miktex, biber

I downloaded the `texmf` tree containing `biber.exe` from 
miktex-biber-bin.tar.lzma

Then I created a tree `c:\localtexmf` and put the `tpm`, `miktex`, `doc` folders there.
I added `c:\localtexmf` to the `%path%` variable.
Still, `biber` is not recognized as a command. What could possibly go wrong? There is no answer for this on TeX.SX. My system is 64-bit Windows 7

I hope it is an interesting problem because other users might have it too,

Avi

Comment: Did you add the path to biber.exe to the path variable?

Comment: The local tree is a TeX thing, not a Windows thing. As such, you need to put the binary on the `%PATH%`. I tend to have a dedicated 'my stuff' directory for this such as `\C:Program Files\local`, so I only need to add one thing to the path variable.

Comment: I added the localtexmf tree to the c:\windows\system32 folder which is already included in %path%. My system is MikTeX 2.9 the 64-bit version on Windows 7. I also updated the MikTeX package database and formats. Still I got the response that biber is not recognized as an internal or external command, executable program or batch file.

Comment: Biber is now included also for 64-bit MikTeX.

Answer (score 2):

Put the biber.exe into MikTex bin path. It is:

`%MIKTEX DIRECTORY OF INSTALATION%\miktex\bin\`

or

`C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\bin`

**EDIT:**

But if you would like a local `texmf` tree, it necessary add the *local bin directory* to the `%PATH%`. In your case it's not only `c:\localtexmf`, it is `c:\localtexmf\miktex\bin` (if necessary, restart the system).